# Obj c adding bytes to uint8_t array between methods?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, byte

I'm having an odd problem with obj c adding an extra byte to by uint8_t array.

Here are the two methods that are involved:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // hexData = NSData object
    const uint8_t *hexBytes = [hexData bytes];

    // header is first 3 bytes
    uint8_t headerBytes[] = {hexBytes[0],hexBytes[1],hexBytes[2]};

    // output the size
    NSLog(@"View did load header size: %lu", sizeof(headerBytes));

    // create a MessageHeader object
    MessageHeader *messageHeader = [[MessageHeader alloc] initWithBytes:headerBytes];
}
```

**MessageHeader.h**

```
- (id)initWithBytes:(uint8_t *)bytes {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil){
        NSLog(@"Message header init bytes size: %lu", sizeof(bytes));
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
        self.bytes = bytes;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Console output**

> View did load header size: 3
>
> Message header init bytes size: 4

This is very strange! Outputting the bytes to the screen shows that an extra byte has been appended to the data for no apparent reason. If `eef231` is the input then `eef23150` is the output in the init method.  That extra byte is seemingly random.

I wonder if it could be the cast between `uint8_t headerBytes[]` and `uint8_t *bytes` in the `init` method.

If anyone has any more info on it that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` is a compile time operator and doesn't do what you think it does.

sizeof on an uint8_t[] gives you the size of that array, which is 1 byte * 3 elements = 3 bytes. It can do this because the array declaration has implicit size information attached.

sizeof on an uint8_t* gives you the size of a pointer, which is 4 bytes on 32 bit systems.

See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Using_sizeof_with_arrays) on `sizeof`  for a good idea of what it does.

If you want to pass the length of the array, the general convention is to pass an additional length paremeter. Since you are working in objective c, you should pass around an NSData, which can contain an array of data, and also its size.

Answer (score 1):

`bytes` is declared as a `uint8_t *` in `initWithBytes`, that is, a pointer to `uint_t`.

The size of a *pointer* is, in the case of your hardware, 4 bytes. It has nothing to do with the array size, which is unknown inside that method.

Comment: Right that makes sense thanks for that. So the next question is, how can I pass a `uint8_t` array instead of a pointer? Or can I not?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in `initWithBytes:`: `sizeof(bytes)` gives you the size of the pointer variable, 4 bytes on a 32 bit architecture.

There's no way of getting the size of the original C array in the called function (at runtime C arrays do not carry size information). You would need to pass the size as an additional argument.

Comment: Ah thanks! Makes sense. Is there any way to pass the original C array instead of a pointer? Or am I doing it correctly?